# How different are Lynis and Wazuh solutions?

Tags: pci-dss, ossec, lynis

It seems both Cisofy's Lynis and Wazuh's OSSEC share a lot of functionalities. I'm completely newbie on both tools and yet I need to pick one (or both) to help achieve PCI DSS Compliance. Any thoughts?

Comment: You will have to look this up in the respective documentation. This question is off-topic here.

Comment: Those are very different tools...

Answer (score 2):

As the author of Lynis, I suggest using both as they both focus on a different aspect of information security.

OSSEC and Wazuh are focused on monitoring files and the status of the system. Lynis helps you with understanding what can be done on a system to improve/increase its security defenses. OSSEC or Wazuh would be run continuously, where you would Lynis daily (cronjob) and ad-hoc while doing system hardening.

If you are interested in learning more about security tools (who doesn't?), I suggest using the [Linux Security Expert](https://linuxsecurity.expert/) project. It is a project I founded to review and explain tools and security concepts. See [Lynis](https://linuxsecurity.expert/tools/lynis/) (Wazuh is to be reviewed).